# Run methods in a ratio

Tags: java, data-structures, logic

I have to call methods according to their weight ratios.

```
id       methodname      weight
1         method1         10 
1         method2         20
1         method3         20
```

These ids will be looped in a for.
The method weight ratio is 10:20:20
Whenever we encounter id as 1-
So the method1 has to be run 20 percent of the time , method2 40 percent of the time and method3 40 percent of the time.

This ratio has to maintained whenever the id is called.
Need to do this using data structures. pls help!!!

Comment: You're almost certainly doing something wrong if you want this. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Is [Thread#setPriority](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority(int)) enough?  Otherwise it sounds like you need your own scheduler.

Comment: That is the exact problem i am trying to solve.the only storage i can use is a properties file.

Comment: You can set priority for thread. But it do not give any guarantee

Comment: This can be very easily solved with `Math.random`, but it's still a very strange thing to want to do.

Comment: What should the thread do? Just consume CPU?

Comment: This now have nothing to do with threads.

Comment: The method has to be called. is thr anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a list of `Runnable` and pick at random from the list with a proportion bias:

```
static int method1Calls = 0;
static int method2Calls = 0;
static int method3Calls = 0;

static final void method1() {
    System.out.println("method1");
    method1Calls += 1;
}

static final void method2() {
    System.out.println("method2");
    method2Calls += 1;
}

static final void method3() {
    System.out.println("method3");
    method3Calls += 1;
}

Runnable call1 = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        method1();
    }

};

Runnable call2 = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        method2();
    }

};

Runnable call3 = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        method3();
    }

};

public void test() {
    // Put the three objects in a list.
    List<Runnable> methods = Arrays.asList(call1, call2, call3);
    // Call them in proportion.
    int[] proportion = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2};
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // Pick one.
        int n = r.nextInt(proportion.length);
        // Run it.
        methods.get(proportion[n]).run();
    }
    System.out.println("method1 called " + method1Calls + " times.");
    System.out.println("method2 called " + method2Calls + " times.");
    System.out.println("method3 called " + method3Calls + " times.");
}
```

Prints at the end:

```
method1 called 26 times.
method2 called 40 times.
method3 called 34 times.
```

To make the number of calls exactly predictable but random you need to use a shuffle mechanism:

```
public void testShuffle() {
    System.out.println("Using shuffle");
    // Put the three objects in a list.
    List<Runnable> methods = new ArrayList<>();
    // Call them in proportion
    Runnable[] runners = {call1, call2, call3};
    int[] proportion = {10, 20, 20};
    // Grow my list.
    for (int i = 0; i < proportion.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < proportion[i]; j++) {
            methods.add(runners[i]);
        }
    }
    // Shuffle it.
    Collections.shuffle(methods);
    // Call them.
    for (Runnable r : methods) {
        r.run();
    }
    System.out.println("method1 called " + method1Calls + " times.");
    System.out.println("method2 called " + method2Calls + " times.");
    System.out.println("method3 called " + method3Calls + " times.");
}
```

This prints:

```
method1 called 10 times.
method2 called 20 times.
method3 called 20 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uniformly distribute method calls between a set of methods then there is a very simple way:

```
Math.random
```

Why? Because it provides the guarantee that this will return a number sampled from the range `[0, 1)` from a uniform distribution. This means that any number in the random is equally likely to be returned.

This is, of course, random so in theory `0.0` could be returned every time from now until the end of time - that is the nature of randomness. But you mention "percentage chance" and that is exactly what this is.

So we need to divide the range into 5 segments, then if the number is:

- in the first segment call `method1`
- in the second or third segment call `method2`
- in the fourth or fifth segment call `method3`

This equates to:

```
final double random = Math.random()
if(random < 0.2) {
    method1();
} else if (random < 0.6) {
    method2();
} else {
    method3();
}
```

Comment: Its a good Solution Boris. Is there anyway to make it generic, as in the ratio can be random like 1:10 or 10:10:10:10 or 15:5 and there might any number of methods for one id.

Comment: I will leave that as an exercise to the @Learner. Hint: how did i work out the numbers in this example?

Comment: In this solution, if i loop id 10 times, method1 has to be called 2 times, method2 4 time, and method3 4 times. There is a chance if the random number less than 0.2 appears 3 times, method1 will be called 3 times. That is nt acceptable for wt i am trying to do.